# Motivo personalizado de fechamento com votos mesmo sem justificar o fechamento em si

Tags: debate, comportamento, fechamento, filas-de-análise

Estava na fila de analise de fechamentos, e me deparei com a pergunta [`Remover cpfs no final da pagina do javaScript que valida CPF`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182944/28595), que possuia 4 votos de fechamento, conforme imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Link na fila: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/98290

Ao clicar no motivo `fora do escopo`, me deparei com este motivo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Bom, posso ter perdido algo, mas a justificativa não diz nada sobre real motivo do fechamento como fora do escopo, já que aparentemente foi escolhida a opção do próprio analista escrever o motivo que o levou a votar o fechamento.

Bom, o que mais me estranhou, além do fato da justificativa não dizer nada com nada, é ainda possuir 2 votos.

Isso poderia ser considerado um mau uso da ferramenta? Caso seja, como proceder para casos semelhantes?

> P.S.: Caso haja algum motivo especial para este motivo de fechamento, gostaria que fosse mostrado, porque realmente não achei nada a respeito e a primeira vista, causa muita estranheza.

Comment: A pergunta esta clara, ela pegou um código da própria rede, e não conseguiu aplicar  no site dela, se bem não me engano quem postou essa sinalização foi o @jbueno e o voto na sinalização foi meu, porque de fato eu concordo, não sei em qual dessas categorias se encaixaria melhor

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio não entendi

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11910?m=35306822#35306822

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio então não foi mau uso, foi apenas um motivo meio confuso no campo.

Comment: Eu não diria que é mau uso da ferramenta - mas o fato de não sabermos o motivo pelo qual estamos fechando algo, não é um indício de que talvez não deva ser fechado?

Comment: De qualquer forma, eu ainda não entendi, os códigos do site podem ser copiados, muitas respostas que obtive aqui eu transcrevi o código para o que já estava escrevendo. O motivo seria plágio ou algo assim? (cc @jbueno)

Comment: Relacionada: [Como proceder quando não tem o motivo correto para excluir](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3984/70)

Comment: Realmente. Removi o voto pra fechar.

Answer (score 6):

Isso é mau uso da ferramenta sim. O fato de o motivo ter sido debatido no chat ou mesmo nos comentários não dá margem para se usar como justificativa "*eu nem sei o que dizer sobre isso*", independente do mérito do fechamento ou da qualidade da pergunta.

A finalidade deste campo é dupla:

- Orientar outras pessoas que estiverem a ver a fila de análise acerca do motivo de fechamento.
- Orientar o autor da pergunta fechada sobre como este pode melhor a sua pergunta.

A justificativa apresentada não atende nenhum destes requisitos. Além disso, em nenhum dos casos quem quer que seja deveria ficar vasculhando mensagens de chat ou de comentários para tentar entender o que foi que aconteceu.

Ressalta-se que o motivo "fora do escopo" -> "outro" é para ser usado apenas em casos muito especiais quando nenhuma das demais alternativas de fechamento for adequada, mas mesmo assim a pergunta deva ser fechada por algum motivo. Assim sendo, é muito importante que esse campo seja preenchido de forma adequada explicando o motivo pelo qual o voto do fechamento está sendo feito. Esse campo não é para ser preenchido "*nas coxas*" ou com qualquer coisa - é necessário esmerar-se na redação do seu conteúdo da mesma forma que fazemos com perguntas, respostas e comentários construtivos.

E se quem for votar para fechar não souber dar uma justificativa para o fechamento, isso é um indício de que ou a pergunta não deveria ser fechada ou quem está fechando ainda não tem maturidade suficiente para fazê-lo.

Comment: Me diga você, a pergunta deveria ser fechada como não esta clara? sendo que estava clara? Ela pegou um código da rede, quis replicar no sistema dela, e não conseguiu remover o "relatório" do cpf no fim a pagina. Vide revisão. Qual motivo você votaria pra fechar? Se e que votaria... Sinceramente eu sinalizaria a pergunta "como esta esquisita demais" :P

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Neste caso, apenas editar a pergunta deixando claro de onde o código foi tirado e acrescentando um comentário alertando a autora da pergunta poderia já ter sido suficiente. Dependendo do caso, os moderadores podem intervir, como já vi intervindo em casos de plágio algumas vezes. Sanado esse problema de possível plágio, a pergunta não tem mais nenhum problema a meu ver que justificasse um possível fechamento.

Comment: Note também que dei essa resposta independentemente do fato de a questão estar bem ou mal-elaborada ou ser ou de ser ou não passível de fechamento - me concentrei no fato de preencher o campo de justificativa de forma inadequada.